# Swift: Writing outputStream

Tags: swift, sockets, tcp, outputstream

I'm testing to connect and send a simple message to a host and I've used this guide http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2016/01/connect-mac-iphone-to-simple-python.html.

So far I'm able to connect to the server and when I tried to write on the output stream .

```
        let data : NSData = "hello".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
        outStream?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
```

I got error on write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), ...

Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'RawPointer'

Comment: Review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Data+OutputStream) for writing `Data` (not `NSData`) to `OutputStream`.